# How to get current user's business unit in Dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

How can I get business unit details of the logged-in user with javascript? I tried Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings but I couldn't get any information for business unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write `Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings` I assume you are working with client-side javascript inside a Model-driven app.

From the userSettings you can get the `userId` property, it returns the GUID of the current user.

After you have this value in order to get details from the business unit of the user you need to do a retrieve request, something like this:

```
// get the userId
var userId = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings.userId;
// remove { and } from the userId
userId = userId.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
// Xrm.WebApi call to retrieve details of the user (fullname)
// and the name of the businessunit (name from expand)
Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveRecord("systemuser", 
userId,
"?$select=fullname&$expand=businessunitid($select=name)").then(
function success(result) {
    console.log(result);
    // Columns
    var systemuserid = result["systemuserid"]; // Guid
    var fullname = result["fullname"]; // Text
    
    // Many To One Relationships
    if (result.hasOwnProperty("businessunitid")) {
        var businessunitid_name = result["businessunitid"]["name"]; // Text
    }
},
function(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}
);
```